# Ruby on Rails get next enum from current model's enum value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, enumeration, enumerable

I'm using an enum in my model defined as such:

```rb
enum role: [:member, :content_creator, :moderator, :admin]
```

I wanted an easy way to get the next role from a user's current role, so I came up with this:

```rb
def self.next_role(user)
  begin
    User.roles.drop(User.roles[user.role] + 1).to_enum.next
  rescue StopIteration
    nil
  end
end
```

In the view, I'd likely add onto this the following method chain: `[...].first.humanize.titleize`.

I'm only somewhat concerned about my solution here, but mainly wanted to know if there was a better (read: more built-in) way to get what I'm after?  I know there are only four enums there and I admit I started my implementation with `if ... elsif ... etc.`.  In other words, I find myself more proficient in Rails than I do with Ruby itself.  Can someone elaborate how one "should" do this?

Comment: Does that handle wrapping? What's "next" for `:admin`?

Comment: Shoot.  Great question.  What do you think of `nil` as a candidate?  I would want the method to convey that there is nothing after `:admin`.

Comment: You're defining non-standard behaviour here so you'll need to make the rules. I'm just saying you need to consider situations like that to be sure it works consistently and in meaningful ways.

Comment: Agreed.  I think that's the way I want it to work, but I see that I get an exception instead of nil in the scenario :(

Comment: I updated my suggested solution to take into account what to say about next role when current role is admin.  Thanks for your input @tadman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`User.roles` is just an `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` that looks like:

```
{ 'member' => 0,
  'content_creator' => 1,
  'moderator' => 2,
  'admin' => 3 }
```

Using that, this solution is pretty close to yours but without the exception handling. I would also be doing this as an instance method on User, not a class method.

Returns the subsequent role as a String, nil if the current role is :admin

```
def next_role
  User.roles.key(User.roles[role] + 1)
end
```

You can then call (ruby 2.3 required for the `&.` safe navigation operator)

```
user.next_role&.humanize
```

Comment: o_0  (I love it).  I really like your solution a lot.

Comment: Is it wrong to be worried about referencing `User.roles` twice?  And I agree with you that this should be an instance method in that I'm always asking for the next enum in reference to the current one of a user.  But I thought it should have been a class method since the whole collection of roles isn't really the concern of a particular user, but more so the concept of a user in general.  Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: In my experience accessing the enum hash is not a performance concern, certainly not in supporting the generation of a view. I think that the bit about 'always asking … in reference to … a user" is what jumps out at me saying: this should be an instance method. Obviously it works either way. Pragmatically, the instance method results in fewer characters to type for the caller :)

Answer (score -1):

How's this grab you? Okay so it's not really more "built in." But I thought it was different enough from your solution (which was pretty clever imo) to throw into the mix, at least to offer some different elements to potentially incorporate.

```
  def self.next_role(user)
    next_role = user.role.to_i + 1
    next_role == self.roles.length ? nil : self.roles.invert[next_role]
  end
```

Comment: I like your solution too!  It definitely gets away from referring to `User.roles` more than once, which is really my biggest gripe with it.  I'll continue mulling it over...

Comment: you also won't need .first at the start of the chain in your view

Comment: I think `user.role` will return a String, the name of the enum, then `.to_i` then turns that into `0`.

Comment: <user_object>.to_i will give you the same as User.roles[<user_object>.role], not always 0.